# Managing VMs of Hyper-V Standalone Server without DC

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, powershell

How am I supposed to manage newly created free Hyper-V Server VMs without DC?

Managing a Hyper-V server in workgroup environment is a pain and I had a lot of problems connecting to my Server and haven't managed that yet.

This is our only server, so we don't have many options.

Firstly, I need to create a VM to have the DC (Domain Controller) created.

I would create new VM in PowerShell, but can't manage VMs from Hyper-V server.

Am I left with the option: Remotely manage Hyper-V server through Hyper-V manager on workstation (Windows 10) joined in the same Workgroup?

Comment: What is DC as spoken of above?

Comment: @juniorRubyist Domain Controller (Windows Server 2016).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Hyper-V thing, it's an environment thing.

This would be the same as you trying to manage on physical workgroup computer to another.

Hyper-V is a W10 feature, and people use it daily and manage the VMS just fine.

You don't need a DC to use / manage Hyper-V VM's, you do need to setup your networking correctly. If you do not, you will have issues.

All must be on the same IP Subnet and the firewalls must be properly configured for communications.

[You can also just use Microsoft's RDCMAN to manage the VM's.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989)